# Listing Self-Taught Credit-Based Courses on Resume

Tags: resume, education

I would like to put them on my resume, because they enhance my profile. I put it under education since it's ongoing; should it be listed somewhere else? I don't want potential employers to skip over it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the combination of "self-taught" and "credit-based".  Did you receive university credits for this work?  If so, how did they validate your self-taught learning -- did you take exams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put it under education since it's ongoing; should it be listed somewhere else?

Putting courses where you received college credit outside of your degrees (whether self-taught or otherwise) in your Education section makes sense.

As a reader of many resumes, that's where I'd expect to find them.

You probably should only list courses that are relevant to your profession or specifically relevant to the job you are seeking.

For example, even if you got credits for a self-taught basket weaving course, don't put that on your resume (unless you are applying for a basket weaver position).

Comment: Nope, they're directly relevant to my B.S. so they're a great addition to my resume. Thank you!

Comment: I'm seeking research positions so these courses are necessary.

Comment: Suggest you use a  `>` to properly format the quoted sentence (I'd do it myself but I can't find anything else to fix to get up to the 6-character edit minimum).